# A php platform install ask me intl extension, but it seems already installed

Tags: php, symfony, intl, orocrm

During orocrm installation (a platform developed with symfony 2) I receive this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Intl\Exception\MethodArgumentValueNotImplementedException' with message 'The   Symfony\Component\Intl\Collator\Collator::__construct() method's argument $locale value 'fr_FR' behavior   is not implemented. Only the locale "en" is supported.  Please install the "intl" extension for full    localization capabilities.' in /Users/ale/Sites/educacloud-  bo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Intl/Collator/Collator.php:80
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/ale/Sites/educacloud-bo/app/SymfonyRequirements.php(619):   Symfony\Component\Intl\Collator\Collator->__construct('fr_FR')
#1 /Users/ale/Sites/educacloud-bo/app/OroRequirements.php(24): SymfonyRequirements->__construct()
#2 /Users/ale/Sites/educacloud-bo/app/oro-check.php(6): OroRequirements->__construct()
#3 {main}
thrown in /Users/ale/Sites/educacloud-bo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Intl/Collator/Collator.php on line 80
```

but I have installed intl extension:

```
# php -i | grep intl
 /usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-intl.ini,
 intl 
 intl.default_locale => it_IT => it_IT
 intl.error_level => 0 => 0
```

and php_info() on my browser give me these results:

```
version 1.1.0
ICU version 4.6
ICU Data version    4.6
```

What is the problem?
thanks
Alessandra

Comment: What version of `symfony/icu` is installed?

Comment: Symfony version 2.3.19. I don't want to change locale, I want to un-traslate some bundles.

Comment: I asked not symfony version but icu-version. You can find it in `composer.lock` file.

Comment: I have the same issue. This happens to me in production (ubuntu 14) and not in dev (debian). In production `php5-intl` triggers the dependency installation of `libicu52`, maybe some backward compatibility issues here

Answer (score 2):

By default, symfony2 is able to manage the "en" extension but to get other language, you have to install the `php-intl` extension.

The easiest option is to install it with the composer, because it expose global variable for you ... etc

All of this is explained here [symfony/components/intl](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html).

For the composer extension installation it's [symfony/components/using_components](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/using_components.html).

So after eading this, you need to execute :

```
composer require symfony/intl
```

-- EDIT

Ok, I'm sorry, I've just test the solution, and the fact is : if you use the symfony component you have only access to "en". I have the same problem as you, my php5-intl extension was installed and activated but the error persisted. For me it was that I continue to write `use Symfony\Component\Intl\DateFormatter\IntlDateFormatter;` at the top of my file instead of using the basic php5 extension.

Answer (score 2):

Do one thing that might be helpful for resolve this error
open php.ini file
remove comment from `;extension=php_intl.dll`

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

and restart the Apache server

Answer (score 1):

You need re install package int1

```
apt-get install php-intl

service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Check solutions:

In Symfony 2.0:

## app/config/config.yml

framework:
  session: { default_locale: it_IT }

In Symfony 2.1+:

## app/config/config.yml

framework:
  default_locale: it_IT

Comment: An installation of Symfony Standard Edition already sets this parameter. I have the same issue with the param already set