# intl extension is not read from php.ini

Tags: php, symfony, pimcore

I have a local installation of Pimcore on my Mac.
I don't use anything like MAMP or Homebrew, but just the normal php/apache/mysql environment.
All worked fine on High Sierra.
Yesterday I upgraded to Big Sur.
Now I get an error message when wanting to load Pimcore.

```
 The Symfony\Component\Intl\Locale\Locale::getPrimaryLanguage() is not implemented. Please install the "intl" extension for full localization capabilities.
```

I found out that it uses the php.ini in folder etc, which by default was named php.ini.default. I removed the .default and made a few changes like

- uncommenting extension=intl
- upload_max_filesize = 20M
- max_file_uploads = 40

When I now check phpinfo() I see that the changes in the two upload values are there, but the intl missing error is still there.

```
php -i | grep intl
```

shows this result:

```
/usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-intl.ini,
intl
intl.default_locale => no value => no value
intl.error_level => 0 => 0
intl.use_exceptions => 0 => 0
```

Do you have any advice what I'm doing wrong or what is missing?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this topic:
[A php platform install ask me intl extension, but it seems already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723804/a-php-platform-install-ask-me-intl-extension-but-it-seems-already-installed)

In the discution you will be refered to the symfony documentation (https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html) and some other tips to solve your problem.

Comment: In the links from your post it says I should uncomment it in the php.ini. I already did that, as I mentioned. The intl and translation packages also are installed in Symfony.

Comment: have you try php --ini to check if you are editing the correct php.ini file?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now.
The module in httpd.conf had the wrong path.